# How to create Transaction Commit and Rollback in Webmatrix.Data.Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix, webmatrix-2, webmatrix-3

I am writing a code for my webmatrix project where transaction commit and rollback is applied.
I am Using mysql 5.1 and innodb database engine for transaction support.

I use

```
db.Connection.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    db.Execute("Insert into tmp_upload_img(`path`,`type`) values(@0)", FullPath,"Fullimage");
                    db.Execute("Insert into tmp_upload_img(`path`,`type`) values(@0)", ThumbPath, "Thumbimage");
                    db.Execute("Insert into tmp_upload_img(`path`,`type`) values(@0)", SmallPath, "Smallimage");
                    db.Connection.BeginTransaction().Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    db.Connection.BeginTransaction().Rollback();
                }
```

But I Not achieve transaction support for webmatrix project.

I know this can achieve with **mysql.data.mysqlclient**, but i want to know it is possible with **webmatrix.data** class ?.

Answer (score 2):

The `Database` class in `WebMatrix.Data` doesn't offer anything in terms of support for transactions. It was designed to make it easy for beginners to get on board with ASP.NET. If you want to use transactions in a Web Pages site, you can use plain ADO.NET code for your data access, or you can use something like the Entity Framework which has transaction support built in.